# Criteriabuilder DATE comparison

Tags: java, hibernate, date, jpa, criteria

I would like to compare a date to a timestamp in the database. I currently use

```java
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.between(eventRoot.<Date>get("time"), dBegin, dEnd));
```

- dBegin = Thu Feb 04 00:00:00
- dEnd = Thu Feb 04 23:59:59

eventRoot

```
private Date time;
```

I also tried formatting the date with the following format, to no success.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

And changing

```
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(eventRoot.<String>get("time"), curDformat));
```

where curDformat is the formatted date to

```
2016-02-04
```

And changing the type to String in my eventRoot.

How would I go about only checking the date with the database? And would this improve performance or is it fine doing it with between?

Answer (score 2):

```
SimpleDateFromat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFromat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date dBegin = dateFormat.parse("2018-02-04 00:00:00");
Date dEnd = dateFormat.parse("2018-02-04 23:59:59");

predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.between(<Date>get("time"), dBegin, dEnd));
```

You could use between, it works too.

Answer (score 1):

The criteriaBuilder predicate for date comparison without time

```java
cb.equal(cb.function("date", Date.class, myObj.get("createdAt")), cb.function("date", Date.class, cb.literal(new Date())));
```

It produces the following SQL where clause.

```sql
where date(myObj0_.created_at)=date(?)
```